# Why is the click event not raised?

Tags: javascript, html, click, addeventlistener

What is wrong with this code? I tested it in IE10 and Firefox but the `click` event was not raised.

```
  <html>
  <head>
  <title>Sandbox</title>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

  <style type="text/css" media="screen">
  #t1, #t2 { border: 2px solid gray; }
  #t2 { background-color: pink; }
  </style>

  <script>
  // Function to change the content of t2
  function modifyText(new_text) {
    var t2 = document.getElementById("t2");
    t2.firstChild.nodeValue = new_text;    
  }

  // Function to add event listener to table
  var el = document.getElementById("outside");
  el.addEventListener("click", function(){modifyText("four")}, false);
  </script>

  </head>

  <body>
  <table id="outside">
      <tr><td id="t1">one</td></tr>
      <tr><td id="t2">two</td></tr>
  </table>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your JavaScript is running before the DOM is ready:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'addEventListener' of null
```

You can't reliably interact with the DOM before it's ready, so move your JavaScript to the bottom of the body.

Just in case you were thinking of using `window.load = function() {...}`, a callback attached to `window.load` won't run until *all* of the resources are loaded, which probably isn't what you want. There's no simple plain-JavaScript alternative to jQuery's `$(document).ready()`, but you could use something from here: [$(document).ready equivalent without jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/799981/document-ready-equivalent-without-jquery)

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
window.onload = function() {
  var el = document.getElementById("outside");
  el.addEventListener("click", function(){modifyText("four")}, false);
}
```